# Not able to install Node 14+ on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nodejs

I tried installing Nodejs 14+ version on my Ubuntu 20.04 using nvm and nodesource PPA with both Sudo and normal user. But I am still getting permision required error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the error, seems like its failing at the curl command. Try reinstalling curl via apt since it may not have the correct permissions if it was installed via snapstore.
A similar post was made on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541374/nvm-getting-permission-denied-with-nvm-install-command) for the same issue.

```
sudo snap remove curl
```

then

```
sudo apt install curl
```